# Утилита сравнения фалов

Tags: java, io

Есть утилита для сравнения файлов "test.txt" и "test1.txt". В командной строке работает исправно. Для запуска вводим 
"java -cp . CompFiles test.txt test1.txt"

(текстовые файлы предварительно помещаются в один каталог и все работает ок)

Но как запустить программу из Eclipse, при этом чтобы сразу указать названия файлов?
При замене FileInputStream(args[0]) на FileInputStream("test.txt") все равно не видит файл в каталоге.

```
import java.io.*;

public class CompFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  if (args.length != 2) { //убедиться, что имена файлов передаются программе
      System.out.println("Использование: Compfiles файл1 файл2");
      return;
  }
// Сравнить файлы  
  try ( FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        FileInputStream f2 = new FileInputStream(args[1]))

  {
      //проверка содержимого файлов 
      do {
          i = f1.read();
          j = f2.read();
         if(i !=j)break;
      } while (i != -1 && j != -1);
      if (i !=j)
          System.out.println("Содержимое отличачется");
      else
          System.out.println("Содержимое совпадает");
  } 
  catch (IOException exc) {
      System.out.println("Ошибка ввода-вывода " + exc);
  }
    }

}
```

Comment: укажите полные пути для файлов или установите рабочую директорию при запуске

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось гораздо проще, чем я думал. 
При вызове из командной строки все работает. Но чтобы задать значения сразу, нужно убрать оператор проверки if или оператор перехода return:

```
if (args.length != 2) { //убедиться, что имена файлов передаются программе
      System.out.println("Использование: Compfiles файл1 файл2");
      return;
  }
```

Утилита видела, что значения командной строки нулевые и переходила в начало через return.

Для указания аргументов напрямую использовать:

```
FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
FileInputStream f2 = new FileInputStream("testdata.txt")
```

Answer (score -1):

В каждой среде разработки в настройках проекта есть возможность указать аргументы командной строки и рабочую папку.
В Eclipse - это место в меню Debug и Run в подпункте Debug Configurations и Run Configurations.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Но есть ли возможность определить аргументы заранее в программе?

Comment: Вы открывали Debug Configurations? Там есть вкладка Arguments.